# Diophantine equation $p^{k}=lk+1$ with $p$ prime and $l,k$ integers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Solve the equation :
$$p^k=kl+1, $$ with $p$ a prime number and $k,l\ge 1$ two integers.

I know that $(p,k,l)=(3,1,2)$ is a solution, but can we find all solutions to the equation ?

Comment: If $k$ is a prime $\ne p$, then $p^{k-1}\equiv 1\pmod k$, so any case of $k$ prime and $p$ a prime $\equiv 1\pmod k$ will do.  Example: $p=1000003$, $k=16667$, $l=$very big. Or $p=1237$, $k=103$, $l=31\, 7133292973\,7433257689\, 4527165641\, 9664246314\, 3676119441\, 170959266 8486282299 3026303253 1566663721 0628266399 3604319006 1960852856 676498989 6329675261 9325604740 6117654053 8672215400 5178098020 910289190 8002537994 1402827808 7049227311 6036767308 6713025323 015760133 8127040507 1256762902 3040055603 8127724862 9005663143 2711359366 015570884$

Comment: Ok thanks ! And if we fix the integer $l$, can we have the smallest prime $p$ for which we  can find $k$ such that $p^k=kl+1$ ?

Comment: If $k$ is any divisor of $p-1,$ then $k$ is a divisor of $p^k-1$

Comment: It is better to fix the prime $p$. The for each $k$, we can determine $l=(p^k-1)/k$ integral. For $k=1$ it always works.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen funny that you decided to post this huge number.

Comment: @Mishikumo2019 If you fix $l$, then $p^k$ grows so much faster than $kl+1$ (even for $p=2$) that you can find all $p,k$ for that $l$ very efficiently

Comment: @Jakobian Indeed, when taking $p=1237$, I should rather have used $k=6$ and the more manageable $l=597127327899969468$.

Comment: You want $p^k \equiv 1 \mod k$.
For example, if 
$p=3$, $k$ can be any member of OEIS sequence [A067945](https://oeis.org/A067945).  This is an infinite sequence, so what do you mean by "find all solutions"?

Comment: For any odd prime $p$, you can take $k$ to be any power of $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COMMENT.- Putting $k=1$ one has $p=l+1$ so there are infinitely many solutions.

With $k=2$ we have the equation $p^2=2l+1$ then since $p=4m\pm1$ there are again infinitely many solutions with $l=8m^2\pm4m$.

It is possible pursue this way for greater values of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

An easy set of solutions will be found for all $p\ge 5$ because those primes have the form $6m\pm 1$. For $k=6$, and any prime $\ge 5$, $p^k=p^6=(6m\pm 1)^6=(36m^2\pm 12m+1)^3=(6M+1)^3=6l+1=kl+1$.